# Is there any event where Hazrat Ali (RA) ordered execution of people who considered him to be divine?

Tags: source-identification, history, ali

Is there any event in which Hazrat Ali(RA) ordered the killing of 40 people because they exceeded the limits of love with Hazrat Ali(RA) and declared Hazrat Ali(RA) to be the God.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a claim for such an event, however whether it is historical is debatable. Some of the stories claim that regarding the following hadith:

> أتي علي ـ رضى الله عنه ـ بزنادقة فأحرقهم
>
> Some Zanadiqa were brought to `Ali and he burnt them.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6922)</sup>

That (at least some of) these Zanadiqa (heretics\apostates\hypocrites) were a group who said to Ali that he was God - i.e. they were [Ghulat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghulat). This is recorded in hadith commentaries and its basis is a narration which has been classed as Hassan in chain as recorded in [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/7112) and there also exist similar traditions in the Shia hadith literature such as [al-Kaafi of Kulayni](https://lib.eshia.ir/11005/7/257).

Comment: Based on the fact Ali used the extravagant method of burning them as opposed to simply killing suggests their apostasy involved something that personally offended him which fits neatly with the hasan hadith